# Ссылки на только созданный объект в Python

Tags: python, сборщик-мусора, метаданные

Подскажите что за 5 ссылок появляются как только я создаю новый класс?

```
class Egclass:
    pass

sys.getrefcount(Egclass)

>>> 5
```

Comment: Новый класс должен быть зарегистрирован в системе типов для всяких внутренних нужд интерпретатора. Что вас смущает?

Comment: Так и думал, просто интересно

Comment: Это ссылки именно на класс, а не на объект. Если вы создадите объект этого класса, и сразу передадите его в sys.getrefcount() (`sys.getrefcount(Egclass())`), то вернет 1 (ровно одна ссылка - аргумент функции `sys.getrefcount()`). Если при создании положите в переменную, а потом эту переменную передадите в `sys.getrefcount()`, то будет уже 2 ссылки.

Comment: И получается что из 5 ссылок на класс одна - переменная-имя класса, вторая - аргумент функции getrefcount, и еще 3 какие-то служебные ссылки.